# Colorbox-rails inline content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, colorbox

After I install colorbox-rails

**followed the directions on this page: http://rubydoc.info/gems/colorbox-rails/0.0.9/file/README.rdoc
**here is what the readme says to use for the link_to

```
<%= link_to "My superb link", "#", :data => { :colorbox => true } %>
```

I added this to my link_to

```
:data => { :colorbox => true }
```

it works does a popup, but I can't get it to link to the content I want. It will display either the page you are on in the colorbox or an error message "This content failed to load."

I am trying to get a contact form in the colorbox.

I am running Rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
<%= link_to "My superb link",show_contact_path(@contact.id), :data => { :colorbox => true } %>
```

**Edit**

You can also do

```
// Called directly, without assignment to an element:
$(".myElement").colorbox({href:"thankyou.html"});

// Called directly with HTML
$(".myElement").colorbox({html:"<h1>Welcome</h1>"});
```

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Just make sure you create the selector for the element `class="myElement"`

Also (credit to One Two Three)

> If the link is external (ie., going to site other than your own
>   application's), you'd need to specify the iframe attribute as follows
>   `:colorbox_iframe => true`

Comment: is there a simpler way? I was thinking that something inline should be easier. Similar to the example here with inline http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example5/

Comment: I've come across this problem, just thought I'd drop you my 1 cent solution. If the link is external (ie., going to site other than your own application's), you'd need to specify the iframe attribute as follows `:colorbox_iframe => true`